# Initializing data frames from matrixes

Tags: r

I am having some problem understanding how to initialize data frames with matrix. When I execute the following:

```
m1 = cbind(1:5,11:15)
m2 = cbind(21:25, 31:35)

d = data.frame(m1)
d$m2 = m2
```

How can I create directly create a dataframe with `m1`, for which `df$m1` would return a matrix, as the `df$m2` does in my example?

Comment: Maybe create a dataframe with an id-variable first, and then do `d$m1 <- m1`? But I"m wondering what you're trying to do with the dataframe of matrices. Would a list serve your needs better?

Comment: You're getting what you want for `df$m2` by coercion. For instance, this will not work: `m1 = cbind(1:5,11:15); m2 = cbind(21:26, 31:36); d = data.frame(m1);  d$m2 = m2`

If you wish to have a `data.frame` that is a block matrix, I suggest you stick to arrays (such as a matrix or multi-dimensional array). 

**What are you actually trying to do?**

Comment: I am simply trying to understand the syntax. I did the `d$m2 <- m2` without understanding the consequences. A nice side effect is `melt(d$m2)`, which seems to do the opposite of a `expand.grid` for the rows and columns of `m2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `I` to specify the matrices should be treated "as is"

```
> d<-data.frame(m1=I(m1),m2=I(m2))
> d$m1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   11
[2,]    2   12
[3,]    3   13
[4,]    4   14
[5,]    5   15
> d$m2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   21   31
[2,]   22   32
[3,]   23   33
[4,]   24   34
[5,]   25   35
```